# Parcelable java.util.Date

Tags: android

I am trying to make one of my classes Parcelable, and one of its attributes is a Date object.

In the writeToParcel() method I have:

```
out.writeLong(myDate.getTime());
```

And in my createFromParcel() method I have

```
person.setDate(new Date(in.readLong() * 1000));
```

The Object that I am passing to my Intent has a Date created like this:

```
new Date(2000,12,06)
```

But, when I read it out on the other side, in the other activity:

```
myDate.getYear()+"-"+myDate.getMonth()+"-"+myDate.getDay()
```

It prints out "2001-0-0"

I'm assuming that something is getting screwed up during the parcel process?

Answer (score 3):

You're writing out milliseconds since the Unix epoch (see [the documentation for `getTime()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29)).

The `Date` constructor that takes a `long` value takes in milliseconds since the Unix epoch (see [the documentation for that constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#Date%28long%29)).

You, instead, are passing, microseconds since the Unix epoch to the constructor. Just pass the `readLong()` value to the `Date` constructor, and see if that helps.

Comment: so are you suggesting that i just remove the *1000?

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in the way you create the Date object, check the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#Date%28int,%20int,%20int%29) for more information about it.

> **Parameters**
>
> year, 0 is 1900 (e.g 100 is 2000).
>
> month of the year, 0 - 11 (e.g. June is 5).
>
> day of the month, 1 - 31 (don't think it needs example).

as you can see, when you do this "**new Date(2000,12,06)**", you are not creating the
date you thought you were creating on the first place. Also please not that the method
was **deprecated since API 1**, so please don't use it, unless you are targeting API 1, that
i don't think anyone is doing it anymore.

Also, as CommonsWare told you, **remove the 1000** at the end while reading.